# What are the prerequisites for Differential Topology?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

I'm looking to do some independent reading and I haven't been able to find rough prerequisites for Differential Topology at the level of Milnor or Guillemin and Pollack.

Is a semester of analysis (Pugh) and a semester of topology (Munkres) enough to make sense of most of it or should I take a second semester of analysis first?

Comment: That should be fine. You'll also need some linear algebra, but if you already know some analysis and topology then you probably know enough linear algebra as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand some set theory, you might like to use Kinsey's "Topology of Surfaces", which is what my class used as a pre/corequisite when we were studying Milnor's "Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint".

They complement each-other nicely; Kinsey is tutorial-like and you could probably get through five pages in a day, whereas Milnor is terse and one page a day (depending on the page!) is a fast self-study pace.

Answer (score 1):

GP itself says a year of analysis and a semester of linear algebra, but based on speeds and all. I'm taking a class based on those books, and what matters most is that you know rigorous multivariable calculus well (Chapter 5 in your Pugh).